# Jasmin invoke local method results in VerifyError

Tags: jvm, jasmin

I'm trying to invoke a local method, pow(), as follows.

My class looks like this.

```
.class public helloworld
.super java/lang/Object

.method public pow(II)I
    ...
.end method

.method public foo()V
    ...
    ldc 1
    ldc 2
    invokevirtual helloworld/pow(II)I
    return
.end method
```

However, this results in the following error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: helloworld, method: foo signature: ()V) Unable to pop operand off an empty stack
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: My full code is below.
Note that pow() is a method that raises the first value to power of the second value:

```
val pow (val v, val pow) {

    val result = v;

    for (val i = 1; i < pow; i++ ) {
        result = result * v;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Complete class:

```
.class public helloworld
.super java/lang/Object

.method public <init>()V
aload_0
invokenonvirtual java/lang/Object/<init>()V
return
.end method

.method public pow(II)I
.limit stack 9
.limit locals 5
iload 1
istore 3
ldc 1
istore 4
label16:
iload 4
iload 2
if_icmplt label22
iconst_0
goto label24
label22:
iconst_1
label24:
ifeq label36
goto label30
label27:
iinc 4 1
goto label16
label30:
iload 3
iload 1
imul
istore 3
goto label27
label36:
ireturn
.end method

.method public foo()V
.limit stack 3
.limit locals 3
ldc 1
ldc 2
invokevirtual helloworld/pow(II)I
return
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
.limit stack 3
.limit locals 2
return
.end method
```

Comment: Why did you not post your complete code? I think the error is in a part you omitted.

Comment: I didn't think that was the issue, but I pasted it below my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call an instance method, you have to put the object on the stack too.

```
aload 0
ldc 1
ldc 2
invokevirtual helloworld/pow(II)I
```

Comment: Would you know how to invoke the method using an array as argument? It works for integers, but not for arrays it seems:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24722634/jasmin-invoke-a-method-using-an-array-as-argument