# Jasmin invoke a method using arguments

Tags: jvm, jasmin

I'm writing a compiler that generates Jasmin code and I want to invoke a method using an argument, as follows:

```
val test(val x) {
    return x;
}

val main (string[] args) {
    test(1);
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.class public helloworld
.super java/lang/Object

.method public <init>()V
aload_0
invokenonvirtual java/lang/Object/<init>()V
return
.end method

.method public test(I)I
.limit stack 4
.limit locals 3
iload 1
ireturn
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
.limit stack 4
.limit locals 3
aload_0
ldc 1
invokevirtual helloworld/test(I)I
return
.end method
```

However, this results in the following error. What am I doing wrong here?

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: helloworld, method: main signature: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V) Incompatible object argument for function call
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with, the code you 'compile' is not Java, and I'm not sure what it is (pseudo-code?).

The problem with your jasmin code is that it seems you want to call `test()` as an instance method of the array, which it isn't, because its an instance method of `helloworld`, which you don't instantiate.

So either you should instantiate the class helloworld, or make test() a static method, so that it can be called without creating an object.

When fixing the jasmin code I also ran into another error: `iload 1` should be `iload 0`. (Programmers like to start counting at 0).

In this code I assume you meant `test()` to be static.

```
.class public helloworld
.super java/lang/Object

.method public <init>()V
aload_0
invokenonvirtual java/lang/Object/<init>()V
return
.end method

.method public static test([Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
.limit stack 4
.limit locals 3
aload 0
areturn
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
.limit stack 4
.limit locals 3
ldc 1
anewarray java/lang/String
astore 2
aload 2
ldc 0
ldc "bar"
aastore
aload_0
aload 2
invokestatic helloworld/test([Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
return
.end method
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that making the method static solved my problem. The language I'm writing the compiler for is one I created myself. However, I have one more question, since I also get the other error. When I recreate the same program in Java and disassemble it with the command javap it does load the first argument of a function with iload_1 (and not iload_0). I thought the 0 register was a reference to itself (which is why you load it with aload_0 when calling a function, as you explained in my other question?)

Comment: Because this is a static method, so the 0 register is the first variable. When it's an instance method, 0 is the `this`.